# Raise of an eoferror for a file

Tags: python, file, eoferror

```
 import pickle
filename=input('Enter a file name:')

def commands():
    f=open(filename,'w')
    names=[]
    grades=[]
    while True:
            name=input("Give a student's name:")
            if name.lower()=='end':
                    f.close()
                    print("File closed")
                    print("Back to Menu")
                    break
            else:
                    x=names.append(name)
                    f.write(str(x))
            grade=input("Give student's grade:")          
            try:
                grade=float(grade)
                if 0<=grade<=10:
                    y=grades.append(grade)
                    f.write(str(y))
                else:
                    print("Please give a grade!Between 0-10! ")
            except ValueError:
                print(grade,"is not a number...Give only Numbers!")




def syn2(filename):
    try:
        f=open(filename,'r')
        f.read(names)
        f.read(grades)
        d1={}
        d1[names]=grades
        print(d1)
        print("Back to Menu")
    except IOError:
        return False
```

WHEN I CALL syn2(filename) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 68, in 
  File "file2.py", line 45, in syn2
NameError: global name 'names' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the end of the file "EOF" before your program expects to.

Comment: So,What I have to do? Sorry...But I'm a beginner. This may seems  rediculous to you...but i cant fix it! :(
(sorry for the 'answer' Im also new on the site!)

Comment: see jellybean's answer for a better solution all around. +1 jellybean

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the students/grades in a dictionary. If the user has finished her input, `pickle` the dictionary into a file. Like

```
grades = {}
while True:
    # ask for student's name n
    # ...

    if n.lower() == 'end':
        break

    # ask for student's grade g
    # ...

    grades[n] = g

pickle.dump(grades, yourfile)
```

Comment: if i do this:

Give a student's name:fae
Give student's grade:2
Give a student's name:rg
Give student's grade:2
Give a student's name:aewe
Give student's grade:3
Give a student's name:feag
Give student's grade:5
Give a student's name:gea
Give student's grade:3
Give a student's name:end
File closed
Back to Menu
.... .... 
then the dictionary is like that:

{'fae': {'gae': {...}, 'fae': {...}}}

Comment: take a look to the edited one...
its not what you suggested...but i think it's similar! ;)

Comment: Doesn't even look close to me... But I'm not all THAT well versed in python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You have the error  `global name 'names' is not defined` because you have declare `names` within `def entoles()` and is only seen within this scope.

You have to declare `names` outside the `dev entoles()` if you want to be able to access it.

Also

```
x=names.append(name)
f.write(str(x))
```

append is a method that append the item passed to the list in-place. The method returns 'None'
Therefore, `f.write(str(x))` will write 'None'.

EDIT:
[Python doc about Input/Output](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for f.read() and [this Python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) for input/raw_input

Comment: well...i declare names outside the 1st function 
but now i have this:


TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: From the python doc:
"To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned;"
And what you currently do is to pass a list to read() instead of a integer(size).

Comment: Also, you may want to use 'raw_input' instead of 'input'. See the docs referring to those methods in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `myfunc` function reopens the file on each iteration, deleting its contents. You should move the `open` call to before the while loop.

Comment: well now i dont have EOFError 
but the dictionary contains only the 1st student and the grade!
:(

Comment: That's because you only `pickle.load` the first student. You can fix this by loading repeatedly, but it's better and easier to follow jellybean's suggestion and pickle the dictionary.

Comment: but why it's only the first?...picle.load is on the loop...and name changes each time    :\

Comment: There is no loop in `syn2`, so only the first one is loaded.

Comment: yes...but from the first one...the names are loades all together.
Why it takes only the 1st?  xmmmm

Comment: can you give me an idea of what you mean?
Thnx in advance